# Different results when lm() is used vs. matrix multiplication formula

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

I am running a simple multivariate regression on a panel/time-series dataset, using `lm()` and the underlying formula $(X'X)^{-1} X'Y$

I'm expecting to get the same coefficient values from the two methods. However, I get completely different estimates.

Here is the R code:

```
  return = matrix(ret.ff.zoo, ncol = 50)  # y vector
  data = cbind(df$EQ, df$EFF, df$SIZE, df$MOM, df$MSCR, df$SY, df$UMP)   # x vector
  
  #First method     
  BETA = solve(crossprod(data)) %*% crossprod(data, return)
  
  #Second method
  OLS <- lm(return ~ data)
```

I am not sure why the estimates are different between the two methods.

Comment: Can't quite tell from your code (it would help if it were reproducible...), but do both models have an intercept?  Also, you don't want to do this "by hand", except possibly for checking your understanding, as there's potential for major numerical issues.  Use `lm`.

Comment: Which one fits your data?  Also, (apologies if you knew this) the `crossprod` function is not the vector crossproduct, so is it doing the function you want?

Comment: `crossprod(X)` does X'X, so it does what it is intended to do in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example isn't reproducible, but if you try it with some dummy data, the matrix formula and `lm` produce the same results when you take out the intercept:

```
set.seed(1)

x <- matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=5)
y <- rnorm(200)

solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% y
              [,1]
[1,] -0.0826496646
[2,] -0.0165735273
[3,] -0.0009412659
[4,]  0.0070475728
[5,] -0.0642452777
> lm(y ~ x + 0)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0)

Coefficients:
        x1          x2          x3          x4          x5  
-0.0826497  -0.0165735  -0.0009413   0.0070476  -0.0642453
```

Comment: Your results are different because you use 2 different models (`lm` includes an intercept by default).

Comment: @Thomas I was not your downvote, but the example you posted clearly shows that the coefs from the two methods do not match.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I just realized the stupid mistake I made, I should have included a vector of 1's in my matrix to take care of intercept! Thanks a lot!